# How would you say someone's on a need-to-know basis?

Tags: phrase-requests

何が英語の「need-to-know basis」の日本語訳なの？

私はよくない日本語だと、すみません。

Comment: Which part of speech do you want? Your title sounds like a state somebody is in but I understand that "on a need-to-know basis" usually means the way information is given (only what is needed, only when it is needed). もっと具体的に（英語でも）教えてください :)

Comment: Basic knowledge is 知る必要、基礎知識.

Comment: JFYI, 大修館ジーニアス英和辞典 says "on a need-to-know basis 必要時に必要情報だけという基準で" and 旺文社レクシス英和辞典
 "on a need-to-know basis 知る必要に応じての方式で"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [article here](http://futurus.blog51.fc2.com/blog-entry-184.html), there is not an exact Japanese term equivalent to it.

It says "*need-to-know basis*" is 「need to know の原則{げんそく}」（「情報{じょうほう}は知{し}る必要{ひつよう}がある者{もの}にのみ伝{つた}え、知{し}る必要{ひつよう}のない者{もの}には伝{つた}えない」という原則{げんそく}）.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki 英語の「need to know」には特別な意味があります。訳し難いので「need to know の原則」とも言います。詳しく: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_to_know

Comment: @siikamiika それはもちろん短い日本語「機密事項」などと表現できます。

Answer (score 1):

Possibly utilizing 知るべき might work in this case to describe the situation. In some cases it might be oversimplified but depending on context it can be used with less problems. However, it works in this sentence:

その情報は知るべき方だけに教えます。

Here, we're identifying a person or group of people who "ought to know." I'm sure that this usage could work in other situations.